# How to use switch condition in javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, switch-statement

I want to use switch condition in JavaScript code. but i dont know how? please help me to do this.. thanks in advance

Comment: Add your code in the question to get better answers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/250256/937962

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
switch(n)
{
case 1:
  execute code block 1
  break;
case 2:
  execute code block 2
  break;
default:
  code to be executed if n is different from case 1 and 2
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a lot of detail in your question but I'll try to help regardless - but without knowing the full scenario its a bit hard to give you a definitive answer.

I'm going to assume you want to handle a redirection on a button click, but with some conditions?

Usually you would use a simple case statement to handle this (or an if/else if there is only two conditions), such as the following (using jQuery for event bindings):

```
<button id="button1">Button 1</button>
<button id="button2">Button 2</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(function() {
    jQuery("button1, button2").click(function(e) {
      switch(jQuery(this).attr("id")) {
        case "button1":
          location.href = "http://clickedonbutton1.com";
          break;
        case "button2":
          location.href = "http://clickedonbutton2.com";
          break;
       default:
          alert("Dont know what happened here....");
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Read [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

1. No restriction on `case value` type.
2. You can use "string" case value in JavaScript
3. You can add duplicate case value. The first matching case value is recognized, regardless of duplicates.

Answer (score -1):

```
switch(youVariable)
{
   case "test1":
   break;

   case "test2":
   break;

   default:
   break;

}
```

Comment: It's not the same.  You can't use strings in switch statements in C++.